# Images in mdpi and ldpi in Android

Tags: android, image, drawable

In my Android app, i have kept some of the images in **"mdpi"** and remaining in **"ldpi"**.
Then also my app is working properly on various devices(Virtual as well as Mobile).
Aren't the images suppose to be fetched w.r.t the Device's Resolution.
How come they are displayed???

Comment: Android scales the images automatically when needed.

Comment: All good explanations provided though they all don't mention that it looks crap on xhdpi devices with mdpi graphic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a very specific algorithm to select the correct drawable. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Android drawable selection]

It is explained in much detail here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Answer (score 1):

mdpi and ldpi are overrides.  If android finds a drawable by the name its looking for it will use it, however if multiple images exist at different resolutions it will pick the closest one.

Comment: ok
So,does that mean,if i'll keep all my images in 1folder,android will use them. But,if i have all images in different resolutions in different folders,android would pick the most appropriate one???

Comment: Yes.  Usually you call it drawable (no suffix).  Then if you want to override it for some resolution you can drop the new image in the drawable-resolution folder, and it will use that new image only for the given resolution.

Comment: ok! got it!
Thank you very much for your help and explanation.
:)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Android scales your **bitmap drawables** *(.png, .jpg, and .gif files)* and [Nine-Patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) drawables **(.9.png files)** so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device.

*For example,* if your application provides bitmap drawables only for the `baseline`, `medium screen density (mdpi)`, then the system scales them up when on a ***high-density screen***, and scales them down when on a ***low-density screen***. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities.

The configuration qualifiers you can use for density-specific resources are `ldpi (low), mdpi (medium), hdpi (high), and xhdpi (extra high)`. *For example,* bitmaps for high-density screens should go in `res/drawable-hdpi`.

For more intimation regarding screens, you should refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Thank you!
So,it is not mandatory to put images in all folders of Drawable.
But it is a good practice to do so!

Answer (score 0):

Scenario is as below:

**Layouts:-**

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default") (320 * 480)
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size (240 * 320)
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size (480 * 800/854)
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size (720/800 * 1280)
```

**Drawables:-**

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density, used by layout-small & layout
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density, used by layout-large
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for xtra-high density, used by layout-xlarge
```

Hope it help. If have any confusion, do ask.
Please do also read once [Screens Support APIs](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.2.html#api)

Thanks.

Comment: when android automatically pick app. img then why do we need to write the permissions in manifest file..

i m asking this in reference to an answer given to somebody..it is as follows

Comment: you have to add this code in manifest.xml file

<supports-screens 
    android:anyDensity="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"/> 

application automatically pick up proper image according to screen resolution.

Comment: Yah, you have to add those permissions too. If you are using the separate layout folders like layout-small, -large, -xlarge & their -land.

Comment: are these layout folders different from ldpi,mdpi, etc.

Comment: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, tvdpi etc are the drawable folders, where u please images-content for various layouts (like: layout, -small, -large, -xlarge etc).

Comment: Yah layout folders are the UIs & drawables are images etc used as per UI.